# Concurrent modification exception from a static method that being called asynctask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have a static method which I am calling from an Asynctask in doInBackGround()

In the method there is this part of code:

```
    ArrayList<Message> messagesList = new ArrayList<Message>();
    if (!clearList) {
        messagesList.addAll(messages.getMessagesList());
            for (Message msg : messagesList) {
                if (msg.getId().length() == 0) {
                    messagesList.remove(msg);
                }
        }
    }
```

It is sometimes throwing 'Concurrent modification exception', I have tried declaring the method as 'synchronized' but it still didn't help, and I cannot declare the block synchronized, since it is a static method and there is no 'this' reference.

I have also tried to stop a running asynctask if I need to start another one, but it didn't help as well.

Help appreciated.

Comment: Thank you for all the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with synchronization. You're using an iterator to loop over `messagesList`, but then using `remove` to modify it during the iteration. You can't do that, because `ArrayList`'s iterators fail when the list if modified during iteration. From [the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html):

> The iterators returned by this class's `iterator` and `listIterator` methods are *fail-fast*: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own `remove` or `add` methods, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Your [enhanced `for` loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.14.2) is just syntactic sugar around using an `Iterator`, so you can just make that explicit and then use the iterator's [`remove` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove%28%29):

```
Iterator<Message> it = messagesList.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    if (it.next().getId().length == 0) {
       it.remove();
    }
}
```

Alternately, you can just use a simple `for` loop running backward and indexing into the `ArrayList` (since `get(int)` is a cheap and constant-time operation on an `ArrayList`, which isn't true of all `List`s):

```
int index;
for (index = messagesList.length - 1; index >= 0; --index) {
    if (messagesList.get(index).getId().length == 0) {
       messagesList.remove(index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Iterators returned by [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) is `fail-fast` in nature.

> The iterators returned by this class's iterator and `listIterator` methods are `fail-fas`t: if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`. Thus, in the face of concurrent modification, the iterator fails quickly and cleanly, rather than risking arbitrary, non-deterministic behavior at an undetermined time in the future.

You can call `iterator.remove();` and change loop based on iterator explicitly rather than implicitly.

```
ArrayList<Message> messagesList = new ArrayList<Message>();
    if (!clearList) {
        messagesList.addAll(messages.getMessagesList());
        for (ListIterator<Message> iterator = messagesList.listIterator();iterator.hasNext();) {
            Message message = iterator.next();
            if (message.getId().length() == 0) {
                iterator.remove();
            }
        }
    }
```

References:

1. [The For-Each Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html)
2. [ArrayList Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will use the iterator.

Comment: @AmitD. Why don't you just provide the link to your answer rather than posting it in each question that appear. Practically, you have copied this answer on `4` different questions asking the same thing, without any change whatsoever. If you see the `share link` below your answer, that is exactly what you need to share your answers.

Comment: @AmitD. Then post it as comment, and it should belong there only. Anyways You're welcome :)

Answer (score 3):

```
 for (Message msg : messagesList) {
                if (msg.getId().length() == 0) {
                    messagesList.remove(msg);
                }
        }
```

In this code you using `messagesList` at a time you are also remove data from `messagesList` thats why you facing error **Concurrent modification exception**..

Here better way for solved your issue. Copy All data in one arraylist for remove & remove all that data from Main List.

```
Message removeMsg = new ArrayList<Message>();
 for (Message msg : messagesList) {
                    if (msg.getId().length() == 0) {
                        removeMsg.add(msg);
                    }
            }

messagesList.removeAll(removeMsg);
```

Comment: Seems a very roundabout way to approach it in view of other options.

Answer (score 2):

The `for` loop is potentially modifying the list over which it is iterating. This is the cause of the exception. The fact that the modification is based on a condition is the reason it does not occur all of the time as the list is not necessarily modified.

Using an `Iterator` is a possible solution, which provides a `remove()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `Synchronize` keyword for this class because static method doesn't belong to any instance

Answer (score 0):

**-** Your problem is **not** associated with synchronization, but the problem of ConcurrentModification you are facing is used to protect collection from taking in object of wrong type.

**Eg:**

Preventing a Cat object enter into a Collection of Dog type.

**-** You can solve this problem by using `Iterator`

```
ArrayList<Message> messagesList = new ArrayList<Message>();

Iterator<Message> itr = messagesList.iterator();

while(itr.hasNext()){

 Message m = itr.next();

 itr.remove();   // Its remove() method of Iterator NOT ArrayList's

}
```